# MySQL: MATCH AGAINST is not showing all results

Tags: mysql, match-against, table-index

I have a strange problem - I use MySQL 5.1 and a table with *Fulltable-Index*. In the mysql config, `ft_min_word_len` is set to 2 (so words with a length of at least two characters are indexed).

The queries below are simplified, but have the same effect as the original one.

When I search for:

```
SELECT company FROM my_table WHERE MATCH (company) AGAINST ('intern*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

I get companies with "internat" in it's name - like "International Inc.", "Internship.org".

However when I search for:

```
SELECT company FROM my_table WHERE MATCH (company) AGAINST ('just*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

I don't get any result, although there is an entry in the table "Justice & Travelling".

But when I search for:

```
 SELECT company FROM my_table WHERE MATCH (company) AGAINST ('travelling*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

I get the "Justice & Travelling"-Entry / correct result.

And if I search with `LIKE %just%` instead of `MATCH-AGAINST`, I also get the correct results.

Does anybody have an idea, why I don't get the correct result in the second mentioned query?

Comment: Have you checked the 'just' isn't a reserved word?

Comment: Yes, I couldn't find it on the list at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/reserved-words.html

Answer (score 1):

Found the troublemaker:
It was because of the stop-words list.
Disabling the list by adding the following line to my.cnf solved the problem:
**ft_stopword_file = ''**

Further Details you can find at the links below:
[MySQL: 11.9.6. Fine-Tuning MySQL Full-Text Search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html)
[MySQL: 11.9.4. Full-Text Stopwords](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-stopwords.html)